# g:select onchange with rest-url

Tags: grails, submit, action, onchange

I want to select a language with a `<g:select>` tag and send the selection params to an action when the selection changes. (The param should be visible in the url of the opened view)

I tried different variations of `<g:form>` and `<g:select>`:

1. **Version creates the correct params, but doesn't create a rest url**:

   ```
   <g:form name="selectLanguage"  <b>action='show' id="${mitarbeiterprofilInstance.id}" lang=lang>
    <g:select onchange="submit();"
     value="${profilInstance?.sprache?.sprache}"
     name="lang"
     optionKey="sprache"
     optionValue="sprache"
     from = "${mitarbeiterprofilInstance.profiles.sprache}" />
   </g:form>
   ```

   Params: `[lang:deutsch, id:3, action:show, controller:mitarbeiterprofil]`

   url: `/mitarbeiterprofil/show/3`

   url should be `/mitarbeiterprofil/show/3/deutsch`
2. **Version adds the params to the url, but with the wrong action**:

   ```
   <g:form name="selectLanguage"  id="${mitarbeiterprofilInstance.id}" lang=lang>
     <g:select onchange="submit();"
     value="${profilInstance?.sprache?.sprache}"
     name="lang"
     optionKey="sprache"
     optionValue="sprache"
     from = "${mitarbeiterprofilInstance.profiles.sprache}"  />
   </g:form>
   ```

   Params: `[lang:deutsch, id:3, action:index, controller:mitarbeiterprofil]`

   url: `/mitarbeiterprofil/index/3/deutsch`
3. **Version chooses the right controller, shows the params in the url, but doesn't use the right parameter**:

   ```
   <g:form name="selectLanguage"  id="${mitarbeiterprofilInstance.id}" lang=lang>
     <g:select onchange="submit(<b>action='show');"
     value="${profilInstance?.sprache?.sprache}"
     name="lang"
     optionKey="sprache"
     optionValue="sprache"
     from = "${mitarbeiterprofilInstance.profiles.sprache}"  />
   </g:form>
   ```

   params:`[lang:show, id:3, action:show, controller:mitarbeiterprofil]`

   url: `/mitarbeiterprofil/show/3/show`

Does anyone else have another idea on how I might go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to play here with **UrlMappings.groovy**

Firstly, let's adjust your form:

```
<g:form name="selectLanguage" action='show' id="${mitarbeiterprofilInstance.id}" >
 <g:select onchange="submit();"
  value="${profilInstance?.sprache?.sprache}"
  name="lang"
  optionKey="sprache"
  optionValue="sprache"
  from = "${mitarbeiterprofilInstance.profiles.sprache}" />
</g:form>
```

And mapping:

```
"/mitarbeiterprofil/show/$id/$lang" (controller:"mitarbeiterprofil", action:"show")
```

This can solve your problem but i'm doubt... So try it and tell us the result :)

P.S. The problem here is in rendering process. Your action url will be created before user selects language. So you have to update url each time user selects language or it will result in url like: /mitarbeiterprofil/show/3?lang=en

Comment: Hi, ive did the Url-Mappings like in your code, but there is no effect... The correct Url is only shown, by accessing the action directly over an url or another view, but not with the g:select.